# Why are x86 processors limited to 8 sockets?

Tags: cpu, computer-architecture, multi-processor, processor-socket

Why are x86 processors only manufactured to operate in, up to, 8 socket systems?
I understand that it's the hardware itself, that determines the number of interconnects a processor has, but why arbitrarily limit the architecture when its RISC competitors don't?

Comment: It also could be no one really needs say a system with more sockets - No point overengineering things when people can 'simply' throw in more nodes

Comment: what makes you think the `limit` is `arbitrary`?

Comment: Even dual socket systems have drawbacks due to the NUMA system used. While each processor has its own RAM, if a program gets migrated to another processor then the memory for that program must be copied between processors or accessed over a shared interlink bus between processors. Just two processors can result in weird performance drops if programs are too tightly coupled, having 8 processors could amplify that to the point where it is actually worse than having a single processor for certain tasks. There is a reason we have been putting more cores in a single package.

Comment: How do you define "socket"? For example, Frontier has 74 cabinets, each cabinet holding 64 blades, each blade consisting of 2 nodes, each node hosting 1 CPU and 4 GPUs. That's 9472 sockets across the whole system, or about 118000% more than 8.

Answer (score 2):

> Why are x86 processors only manufactured to operate in, up to, 8 socket systems?

They aren't. For example, the Huawei KunLun 9032 has 32 sockets capable of hosting Intel Xeon E7 v3 CPUs. The Huawei Node Controller which is used for interconnecting the CPUs in this system actually supports 64 sockets as well.